# How are Microsoft Booking Appointments linked with Calendar Events?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-calendar

If appointments are scheduled with Microsoft Booking calendar entries are created for the staff. Given we have the resource ID of an appointment booking: How can we find the corresponding calendar event of the booked stuff through the Microsoft GraphAPI?

My research did not show any link between the two and also in the documentation I could not find a mention of how those are related. But for sure such a relation must exist because otherwise rescheduling or deletion of appointments could not be handled.

Comment: Could you share more details? You created a bookingAppointment by calling endpoint POST /solutions/bookingBusinesses/{id}/appointments and when you call endpoint GET /solutions/bookingBusinesses/{id}/calendarView?start={start-value}&end={end-value} you can't find them?

Comment: You want to search them by start and end time? Assume you have multiple staff and they have meeting at the same time and multiple appointment booked at this time, how do you know which appointment links with which staff event?